# HttpURLConnection helped me avoid NullPointerException

Tags: java

I encountered this really strange thing while using the HttpURLConnection today. I have the below code that basically reads data from a URL, and stores the data (after parsing it to a java object using GSON) into a Java object. The data is also simultaneously stored in another object that I have serialized and saved to a file. In the event my URL is not accessible, I read the data from the file. The URL is a secure URL that I can only access over the VPN. So to test my program, I disconnected from the VPN to see if I am able to read data from the file. The first code below throws me a null pointer, while the second one doesn't. The only difference as you can see is I am using HttpURLConnection in the second example. How does using it help? Anyone encountered something similar, or am I overlooking something? ;)

**Code that throws nullpointer when URL can't be accessed** -

```
public static void getInfoFromURL() throws IOException {
    Gson gson = null;
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String inputLine = "";
    try {
        gson = new Gson();
        url = new URL(addressURL);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            addressData = ((AddressData) gson.fromJson(inputLine,AddressData.class));               
        }                   

    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        logger.error("Malformed URL exception " + mue+ " occured while accessing the URL ");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("IO exception " + ioe+ " occured while accessing the URL ");
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null)
            bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

**Code that works fine**:

```
public static void getInfoFromURL() throws IOException {
    Gson gson = null;
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection =null;
    String inputLine = "";
    try {
        gson = new Gson();
        url = new URL(addressURL);          
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //This seems to be helping
        connection.connect();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            addressData = ((AddressData) gson.fromJson(inputLine,AddressData.class));               
        }                   

    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        logger.error("Malformed URL exception " + mue+ " occured while accessing the URL ");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("IO exception " + ioe+ " occured while accessing the URL ");
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null)
            bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: if "throws nullpointer", could you attach the stacktrace to your question?

Comment: I tried running your code on my PC, and it doesn't fail. It properly throws a `ConnectException`, which is caught by the catch block. I'm using OpenJDK 1.7.0_25, 64bit, Linux. Which JVM are you using?

Comment: Nope, it throws a nullpointer exception - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.global.usa.test.myapp.util.Test.getInfoFromURL(Test.java:54)

Comment: The line 54 is a line number in the code where this method is called. When you say you didn't get the error, how did you try to reproduce it? In my case, I had to make sure the URL is not accessible, so I had to get off of my vpn. Just curious to know what did you do to reproduce it? For a simple URL, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: When you say '54 is a line number in the code', *which* line is it the line number of? And why haven't you posted the stack trace yet? It it a secret?

Comment: Not a secret. The code is confidential. That's the reason why I haven't posted it.

Comment: @rickygrimes - Well my answer to your question is confidential too.

Comment: I understand you'd need the stack trace to analyze the problem. I am really sorry I can't paste the entire code here at this point. My question here is very relevant to what is mentioned in Oracle documentation in this link - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html. In the document it states - The output from this program is identical to the output from the program that opens a stream directly from the URL. You can use either way to read from a URL. However, reading from a URLConnection instead of reading directly from a URL might be more useful.

Comment: While it says the behavior is identical in both cases, in my case though I see a difference, and I don't understand why :(